# Hidding the runfile() command in Spyder 4.0

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I was hoping that this would be fixed in the newer version but I see the same thing.  Every time a file is executed the console displays the runfile() and wdir and it clutters the console.  Is there a way to hide this?

runfile('C:/Users/One/Desktop/Training/Week1/Files/file1.py',wdir='C:/Users/One/Desktop/Training/Week1/Files/file1.py'), wdir="/directory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way (and there's never going to be one) to hide that command because it's needed to evaluate your code in the console.

However, we're thinking to remove the `wdir` part, unless users declare a specific working directory to run their files.

Comment: Carlos, I've seen you answer this question the same way in several different forums, but I'm confused because I'm running Spyder 4 on a PC and I have never, ever, ever, not one single time had this command appear on my console after executing code, either from the script editor or the console. Not once. A friend just started trying to use Spyder and we just spent an hour trying to figure out why this showed up in her console every time she ran code in the script editor. Are you aware that this does NOT show up for some people?